# Unable to switch staging table back into partitioned table

Tags: sql-server

Please see the issue below. Any help would be appreciated. The same procedure worked fine on a similar database using the same partition function definition. The partitioned table is identical to the staging table except that the staging table contains constraints.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [CO_CODE_RANGE](nvarchar(255)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'00001', N'00005', N'00009', N'00012', N'000136', N'00015', N'00016', N'00020', N'00021', N'00025', N'00026', N'00027', N'00028', N'00030', N'00031', N'00032', N'00035', N'00040', N'00045', N'00050', N'00055', N'00056', N'00057', N'00058', N'00059', N'00060', N'00061', N'00062', N'00063', N'00064', N'00065', N'00066', N'00067', N'00069', N'00070', N'00073', N'00075', N'00076', N'00077', N'00079', N'00081', N'00083', N'00084', N'00085', N'00087', N'00089', N'00096', N'00097', N'00104', N'00105', N'00151', N'00170', N'00350', N'00G82', N'00N82', N'00S82', N'00SW2', N'14086', N'14088', N'20350', N'30350', N'40350', N'50350')


select top 0 * into FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP from FDM.F_GL_PREM

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cx_cs_F_GL_PREM_SP 
  ON FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)

ALTER TABLE FDM.F_GL_PREM SWITCH PARTITION 58 TO FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP

select distinct ETL_SRC_CO_CODE from FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP   
00SW2


ALTER TABLE FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_F_GL_PREM_SP CHECK (([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE]=('00SW2')))
ALTER TABLE FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_F_GL_PREM_SP2 CHECK (([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE] is not null))

ALTER TABLE FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP 
  SWITCH TO FDM.F_GL_PREM PARTITION 58
```

> Msg 4982, Level 16, State 1, Line 41 ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement
> failed. Check constraints of source table
> 'FDW_FDM.FDM.F_GL_PREM_SP' allow values that are not allowed by
> range defined by partition 58 on target table
> 'FDW_FDM.FDM.F_GL_PREM'.

TEST Data:

```
Create table dbo.part_test (ETL_SRC_CO_CODE nvarchar(255) NOT NULL, PART_ID int NOT NULL) ON [CO_CODE_RANGE_SCHEME]([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE])

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [cx_cs_part_test] ON part_test WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) on [CO_CODE_RANGE_SCHEME]([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE])

insert into dbo.part_test values ('00059', 1);

insert into dbo.part_test values ('00089', 2);

insert into dbo.part_test values ('00350', 3);

select top 0* into dbo.part_test_s from dbo.part_test

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [cx_cs_part_test_s] ON part_test_s WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)

alter table part_test switch partition 54 to part_test_s

ALTER TABLE part_test_s WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PART_TEST_S CHECK (([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE]=('00350')))
ALTER TABLE part_test_s WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PART_TEST_S2 CHECK (([ETL_SRC_CO_CODE] is not null))

alter table part_test_s switch to part_test partition 54
```

Comment: Please add the table definition and insert script with sample data to replicate the problem

Comment: The odd thing is that I'm not able to reproduce like this:

Comment: I've added the test data to the original problem under TEST Data

Comment: Just create your staging table on the same partition scheme, and then you don't need to create check constraints, and you'll always be able to switch partitions.

Comment: Creating the staging table on the same partition schema will work well for the next time. Currently though data for 3 separate tables is stuck in staging tables and I'm unable to switch them back in. Any ideas on how to switch those 3 non partitioned staging tables back in?